# python django mock cache

Tags: python, django, caching, mocking

In my settings.py , I have specified my cache as :

```
 CACHES = {
    'default': {
     ......
   }
}
```

In my views.py, I have

```
import requests
from django.core.cache import cache, get_cache

def aview():
    #check cache
    if not get_cache('default').get('key'):
        #make request and save in cache
        result = request.get('some_url')
        get_cache('default').set('key', result)
        return result
    else:
        return get_cache('default').get('key')
```

Now in my tests.py, I have been able to mock requests.get('aurl'), so that makes sure that no external requests are made.

But the test code still hits the cache and gets/sets from it. So if my prod has already set the cache, then test is failing because it gets the data from same cache. Or if I run my tests first, then the test case is setting the cache with test data and I see that same reflected when I run prod website.

How can I mock the calls to

```
get_cache('default').set('key', result)
```

and

```
get_cache('default').get('key')
```

so that the set call does not sets the real cache ( return None?) and get does not return anything in actual cache.

Please provide me with code sample to how to get this done.

Here is how I have mocked my requests.get

```
def test_get_aview(self):
    with mock.patch('requests.get') as mymock:
        mymock.side_effect = (lambda url: MOCKED_DATA[url])
```

What code can I put after this to make it work? I tried something like

```
class MockCacheValue(mock.MagicMock):
    def get(self, key):
        print 'here'
        return None
    def set(self, key, value):
        print 'here 2'
        pass

def test_get_aview(self):
        with mock.patch('requests.get') as mymock:
            mymock.side_effect = (lambda url: MOCKED_DATA[url])
            mock.patch('django.core.cache.get_cache', new=MockCacheValue)
```

but it does not work and putting a print statement inside get/set above does not print anything giving me an idea that its not mocked properly

Comment: Why are you running tests on your production machines?

Comment: @kashif, why don't you use [dummy cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs/#dummy-caching-for-development) while running your tests?

Comment: @Alexander, the cache I am using above in my actual code is file system https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs/#filesystem-caching . How can I specify another value for 'BACKEND' in 'default' cache while running my test cases and still make sure that the actual code in views.py accesses file system based?

Comment: @kashif, decided to answer, please, check.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you should use [dummy cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs/#dummy-caching-for-development) while running tests by:

- overriding settings in test cases, see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/tools/#overriding-settings)
- checking what cache backend to use while testing right in settings.py:

  ```
    CACHES = ...
    if 'test' in sys.argv:
        CACHES['default'] = {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',}
  ```
- having a separate settings.py for testing
- mocking, see good [article](http://www.2general.com/blog/2012/08/09/changing_django_cache_backend_between_test_cases.html) on how to do it

Hope that helps.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/overview/#overriding-settings is a dead link.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/tools/#overriding-settings is the current version of that dead link - I added an edit to the answer - it should be approved soon.

Comment: Also, to add to the answer: dummy_cache is great if you want to turn caching off, if you want to actually test caching, I would recommend the local memory cache https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching